# Why doesn't my .htaccess work when the URL includes a real file name?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to pass all requests within a certain subdirectory to a file called "handler.php".  The .htaccess I have in place works if the URL is not an actual file name, but not if I enter the name of a real file; it instead loads that file directly, never hitting handler.php.

Could someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here?  The .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ handler.php?url=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /handler.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?  I want all requests to pass the url into handler.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule doesn't match real files, because the conditions say so

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

These conditions match, if the request does not (`!`) match a real file (`-f`) and if it doesn't match a real directory (`-d`).

---

If you want to handle all requests no matter what, remove these conditions. You can also remove the first rule, because it is handled by this one too. This leaves just the second rule, but you must prevent a rewrite loop with another condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/handler\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /handler.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```